# Laravel 5.3 Rest API login

Tags: php, rest, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.3

I have a trouble while attempting to create login for rest API using Laravel 5.3. 
I created a student model which extends User, it has email and password (in migration).

This is the guards (I have changed the provider to students)

```
  'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'students'
    ],
],
```

And this is the providers

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'students' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Student::class,
    ],


    'teachers' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Teacher::class,
    ],
],
```

I want to make a login API (rest) using student's credentials. If login is successful the server should return personal information of student. I have searched laracasts a lot but didn't find something similar. And there are a lot changes in new version. so I am confused.

Student **login** function

```
public function login(Request $request){

    if (Auth::check(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
        //$student = Student::where('email',$request->email)->first();
        $student = Auth::user();
        $student->api_token = str_random(60);
        $student->save();
        return response([
            'status' => Response::HTTP_OK,
            'response_time' => microtime(true) - LARAVEL_START,
            'student' => $student
        ],Response::HTTP_OK);
    }

    return response([
        'status' => Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST,
        'response_time' => microtime(true) - LARAVEL_START,
        'error' => 'Wrong email or password',
        'request' => $request->all()
    ],Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);

}
```

neither the `Auth::check()` method nor the `Auth::validate()` work in this case. What can be the problem? How do I implement login for rest api?

Comment: Why not go for JWT?

Comment: REST, by definition, is supposed to be stateless. Therefore, a login doesn't sense, which is why you may not find info by searching on a REST login.

Comment: @Devon the HTTP Request is stateless, it doesn't mean you can't require a token to process. You just can't rely on the server remembering who you are.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu, that wouldn't really be logging in then, that would be generating a token.  That is what I was getting at.

Comment: i think Auht::check() is only for checking if user is authenticate or not  try Auth::attampt() function instead of Auth::check()

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu the JWT somehow also doesnt work, The API is designed for android/ios, so users should be able to login from them, that's why i need authentication

Comment: That's more reason to want JWT.

Answer (score -1):

I have some problem with you..

I used laravel trait, overid some method and create a ApiController for handel ever respond

please check it out:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class ApiController extends BaseController
{
    protected $statusCode=200;

    public function getStatusCode()
    {
        return $this->statusCode;
    }

    public function setStatusCode($code) 
    {
        $this->statusCode = $code;
        return $this;
    }

    public function respondNotFound($message = 'Not Found')
    {
        return $this->setStatusCode(404)->respondWithError($message);
    }

    public function respondInternalError($message = 'Internal Error')
    {
        return $this->setStatusCode(500)->respondWithError($message);
    }

    public function respondUnathourize($message = 'Login Failed username or password doesnt match')
    {
        return $this->setStatusCode(401)->respondWithError($message);
    }

    public function respond($data, $headers=[])
    {
        return response()->json($data,$this->getStatusCode(), $headers);
    }

    private function respondWithError($message) 
    {
        return $this->respond([
            'error' => [
                'message'=>$message,
                'status_code' => $this->getStatusCode()
            ],
        ]);
    }

}
```

and this is my login controller (AuthenticateController.php)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;

class AuthenticateController extends ApiController
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers,ValidatesRequests;

    public function login(Request $request)
    {        
        $this->validateLogin($request);

        // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
        // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
        // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
        if ($lockedOut = $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        $credentials = $this->credentials($request);

        if ($this->guard()->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }

        // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
        // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
        // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
        if (! $lockedOut) {
            $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
        }

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }

    protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {               

        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
        $this->setApiKey();
        return $this->respond([
           'data'=>$this->guard()->user() 
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the failed login response instance.
     * @overide
     */
    protected function sendFailedLoginResponse()
    {
        return $this->respondUnathourize();
    }    

    private function setApiKey()
    {
        $user = $this->guard()->user();
        $user->api_token = sha1(date("Y-m-d H:i:s").$user->name);
        $user->save();
    }
}
```

hope it will help

cheers

Hendra